# I'm trying to install python3.8.1 and when i run './configure' its brings this error

Tags: python

I'm trying to install python3.8.1 and when i run './configure' its brings this error

```py
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.8... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "linux"
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/sysroot/home/endless/Downloads/Python-3.8.1':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See 'config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Can you execute `gcc -v` in the terminal and observe the output?

Comment: I have executed it and output is... bash: gcc: command not found

Comment: Do you had a look at the docs, how to compile Python https://devguide.python.org/setup/#linux, to make sure all dependencies are installed.

Comment: Your link https://devguide.python.org/setup/#linux is not opening

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Maybe you should try a precompiled package?

The error report you saw is the way `./configure` script misses a C compiler which is a requirement for compiling Python from source:

```
...
checking for gcc... no
...
```

Compiling from source may be a tricky task. Besides it requires a lot of time. That's why many operating systems got precompiled packages that may be located in some places other than official repositories.

**Installing on Ubuntu**

For example, Ubuntu got `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` that can be used to install python 3.8. That's how it works:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-distutils
```

And that's it - you got brand new python 3.8 on your machine.

Comment: when I execute this command   'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa',   I get this response   'sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found'.   What could be wrong?

Comment: @AnthonyShamoya well, maybe you got some other operating system. Which one you use?

Comment: I am using Linux endless 5.3.0-23-generic #25+dev115.a7cc8cdbeos3.7.2 SMP Fri Nov 22 22:10:12 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux